# How to locate JLabels to an absolute position on Java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, layout-manager

I have many `JLabel`s (which includes `ImageIcon`s) in a `JPanel`.

And this `JPanel` is only a panel on the GUI; there are lots of other panels.

I want to place labels to the exact pixel coordinates on their `JPanel` container.

How can I do that without using `GroupLayout`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [Doing Without a Layout Manager (Absolute Positioning)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) in the Java tutorials.

> Creating a container without a layout manager involves the following steps.
>
> 1. Set the container's layout manager to null by calling `setLayout(null)`.
> 2. Call the `Component` class's `setbounds` method for each of the container's children.
> 3. Call the `Component` class's `repaint` method.

Answer (score 3):

Either

- set a custom [`LayoutManager`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html) ([`Container.setLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setLayout(java.awt.LayoutManager))) on the panel that sets the exact positions you want or
- set a `null` layout manager (`myPanel.setLayout(null);`) and set component positions externally ([`Component.setBounds`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds(java.awt.Rectangle))).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at MigLayout, which allows you to do absolute positioning, it's not part of the JDK, [but a seperate download](http://www.miglayout.com/).

It's very good as far as layout managers go and does absolute positioning, plus a whole load of other things.

Comment: then how to set absolute position with miglayout?