# How to position two JPanels diagonal from each other in Java?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I was wondering what layout or hack could be used to position these two JPanels so that it would end up looking like this?

[image]

It seems like most layouts depend on the position of other components and either positions them vertically or horizontally in respect to the other components.

Note: Panel 2 is smaller than panel 1.

Comment: It is possible to use *absolute* layout (e.g. `setLayout(null);`) and set your `x,y` as you like

Comment: @iTech, Do not recommend the null layout manager.

Comment: @mre, It is just an option even if it is not the recommended one.

Comment: @iTech, the last option, yeah.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869245/how-to-locate-jlabels-to-an-absolute-position-on-java-gui

Comment: GridBagLayout will do this and it would honour the preferred size of the components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) layout manager in combination with [`Box`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html). But there are several other options. This is just my personal preference.

For more information, please see [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).

Comment: +1 for `Box`/`BoxLayout`; also consider `OverlayLayout`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13437388/230513).